# ASP.NET core WEB API with AD FS authentication

Tags: node.js, authentication, asp.net-core

I have small RESTful API written in ASP.NET core and I am looking into how to add authentication to it using Active Directory. I have to use our companies server for authentication using AD but I do not see any tutorials of how to do this.

I guess that JWT authentication is not what I am looking for or I might be wrong and misunderstand something. I am total noob in question of authentication.

I know we have solved that in one of the nodejs project of ours and it was not that straight forward. I would appreciate any help in that matter.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[As of today](https://github.com/dotnet/corefx/issues/2089), System.DirectoryServices hasn't been implemented in ASP.NET Core yet, but we could use [Novell.Directory.Ldap.NETStandard](https://github.com/dsbenghe/Novell.Directory.Ldap.NETStandard).

You can install the package via NuGet [Novell.Directory.Ldap.NETStandard](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Novell.Directory.Ldap.NETStandard/).

*Sample code* -

```
using Novell.Directory.Ldap;

namespace YourNamespace
{
    public class LdapAuthenticationService : IAuthenticationService
    {
        public bool ValidateUser(string domainName, string username, string password)
        {
            string userDn = $"{username}@{domainName}";
            try
            {
                using (var connection = new LdapConnection {SecureSocketLayer = false})
                {
                    connection.Connect(domainName, LdapConnection.DEFAULT_PORT);
                    connection.Bind(userDn, password);

                    if (connection.Bound)
                        return true;
                }
            }
            catch (LdapException ex)
            {
                // Log exception
            }
            return false;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you for the answer. Unfortunately I cannot use LDAP because of some policies. I will accept your answer because if there no AD solution now I would not get any instructions of how to make one...